# How to recieve Refresh token by using react-oauth@google package in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-console

I am trying to authenticate a user in react via google oauth.
I have used react-oauth@google as a package and i am recieving credentials as a response,
i am getting an access token but not refresh token i also want refresh token to store this in my Database. I have also tried the way of getting auth-code and then by this auth-code getting the refresh token at backend but , I am not able to do it.. I am recieving an error of redirect_uri_mismatch or invalid_grant...

below is my frontend code.

```
import {
  GoogleLogin,
  useGoogleOneTapLogin,
  useGoogleLogin,
} from "@react-oauth/google";

const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (tokenResponse) => {
      console.log(tokenResponse);
    },
    onError: (error) => console.log(error),
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/steps",
    flow: "auth-code",
  });



 <button
        className="btn btn-success"
        onClick={() => {
          login();
        }}
      >
        Sign in with Google 
      </button>
```

`below is my backend code`

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");



const oauth2client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
  clientId:
    "",
  clientSecret: "",
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/steps",
});

const scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
];



exports.getRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const code = req.body.code;
    const url = oauth2client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: "offline",
      scope: scopes,
      include_granted_scopes: true,
      state: JSON.stringify({
        callbackUrl: req.body.callbackUrl,
        userID: req.body.userID,
      }),
    });
    const tokens = await oauth2client.getToken(code);
    res.json({ tokens });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data);
    res.status(400).json({ err: err.response.data });
  }
};

`this is my route`


router.route("api/v1/refreshtoken").post(getRefreshToken);
```

can anybody Please help me get refresh token of client

Thank You In advance :)

I have tried react-oauth@google package but i am unable to find refresh token